# Can I swap an IRF7319 Dual MOSFET for another cheaper one?

Tags: mosfet

I am a noob at electrical work and I want to put [this little project](http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/raspberry-pi/on-off-power-controller) together

There is a [IRF7319 Dual MOSFET](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irf7319.pdf) in the diagram, and this is the first time I've come across this component. Can I replace it with another MOSFET of similar rating? e.g. [DMC3028](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/104c/0900766b8104c6bf.pdf). If not then what can I use and what should I be looking for?

RS Online lists as follows:

[IRF7319 £1.77](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/mosfet-transistors/5410301/)  and [DMC3028  30p](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/mosfet-transistors/7514060/)  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more options than you think: -

[image]

The dual device specified need not be a dual device and this frees up the design to find a really good P channel FET whilst not worrying too much about the performance of the N channel FET.

The three important parameters for the P ch fet are

1. voltage rating (OK),
2. RDS(on) (also OK) and
3. Vgs(threshold) (also OK).

The N channel can be virtually any old N channel because it doesn't get called to conduct power supply amperes.

By the way the DMC3028 looks fine (better than the original for this design)

Comment: For the purpose indicated in the question, even the cheaper [Vishay Si4562DY](http://www.vishay.com/docs/70717/70717.pdf) seems to fit the bill, [22.5p each in lots of 10](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/10PCs-Si4562DY-MOSFET-FET-4562-VISHAY-MINI-Z-KYOSHO-/321155530275?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4ac65c7e23) on eBay. What do you think?

Comment: @AnindoGhosh The Si4562 is far better at a defined Vgs(th) - 1.6Vmax - it is not specified on the IRF device and at 3V on the DMC device. It's only a 20V device but I don't see that as a problem. You have this scary habit of finding good FETs dude!

Comment: Let's just say I love MOSFETs. :-)

Comment: Wow thanks for that. The ebay link was great too, as ebay is only giving me 1 result for Si4562DY, when clearly there are more! (Agghh! UK-only filter was stuck on from earlier, D'oh!)